# Div shifting after ng-show using Bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following:

[image: Before click]

when I click on the picture on the right, I get the following:

[image: After click]

The two boxes should be aligned, like in the first picture.

The containing div is as follows:

```
<div align="center" class="top-buffer">
    <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <img id="face-img" class="search-face" ng-src="{{faceImg}}">
    </div>
    <div class="overlaid img-thumbnail">
      <img id="face-img" class="search-face" ng-src="{{processedResults[selectedSearchResultIndex].img}}" ng-hide="showSearchResultDetails" ng-click="toggleSearchResultDetails()">

      <div class="search-face wrapword" ng-show="showSearchResultDetails" ng-click="toggleSearchResultDetails()">
        Name: <strong>{{processedResults[selectedSearchResultIndex].name}}</strong>
      </div>

      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign overlayer text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the custom CSS is as follows:

```
.search-face {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.overlaid {
    position: relative;
}

.overlayer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 84px;
    left: 85px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #666666;
    color: white;
}

.wrapword {
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
}

.top-buffer { 
    margin-top: 10px; 
}
```

Sorry for the blue scribble!

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You code and fiddle is not enought to know what are you want to accomplish, maybe something like this

```
<div align="center" class="top-buffer">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 text-right image-over">
        <div class="img-thumbnail">
            <img id="face-img" class="search-face" ng-src="{{faceImg}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 text-left image-over">
        <div class="overlaid img-thumbnail">
            <img id="face-img" class="search-face" ng-src="{{processedResults[selectedSearchResultIndex].img}}" ng-hide="showSearchResultDetails" ng-click="toggleSearchResultDetails()">

            <div class="search-face wrapword" ng-show="showSearchResultDetails" ng-click="toggleSearchResultDetails()">
                Name: <strong>{{processedResults[selectedSearchResultIndex].name}}</strong>
            </div>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign overlayer text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9314/

Also if you are uing bootstrap, please dont use align=center
According to the HTML5 CR, which requires continued support to “obsolete” features, too, the align=center attribute is rather tricky.

Comment: What is missing from my description? The first image shows two 'boxes' that are aligned. When I click on the right 'box' it shifts downward... what I want is for the box to stay aligned with the box on the left. This issue is to do with the content of the box on the right affecting its position.